# Does blockcipher decryption always offer equivalent security as blockcipher encryption?

Tags: block-cipher, provable-security

I'm not sure if anyone explored this area before. Blockcipher encryption definitely fullfills IND-CCA, but what about its inverse? Is there a proof that shows blockcipher decryption is as secure as encryption? Or is there an counter-example? Or it's an open problem?